# Prepare Git source control environment using git extensions

Tags: git, github, git-extensions

I am trying to use Git extensions for maintaining a source control versioning of my projects so I have installed Git extensions (I have visual studio 2010 express so as it does not support plugins I need to use Git extensions through its GUI).

I want to use my google drive. In google drive I have created a directory structure like below for all my projects for all my customers:

```
All my Projects (root)
  |
  |__ Customer A
  |       |
  |       |___ Demo Project 1
  |       |        |
  |       |        |__ Develop
  |       |        |    
  |       |        |
  |       |        |__ Feature
  |       |        |
  |       |        |__ Hotfixes
  |       |        |
  |       |        |__ Master
  |       |        |     
  |       |        |
  |       |        |__ Release
  |       |
  |       |___ Demo Project 2
  |       |        |
  |       |        |__ Develop
  |       |        |
  |       |        |__ Feature
  |       |        |
  |       |        |__ Hotfixes
  |       |        |
  |       |        |__ Master
  |       |        |
  |       |        |__ Release
  |
  |__ Customer B
         |
         |___ Demo Project 1
         |        |
         |        |__ Develop
         |        |
         |        |__ Feature
         |        |
         |        |__ Hotfixes
         |        |
         |        |__ Master
         |        |
         |        |__ Release
         |
         |___ Demo Project 2
         |        |
         |        |__ Develop
         |        |
         |        |__ Feature
         |        |
         |        |__ Hotfixes
         |        |
         |        |__ Master
         |        |
         |        |__ Release
```

Initially this directory structure has no data (it's empty). Now I have copied my initial project just started for customer A under "Demo Project 1\Master". Over the time I will do releases for this project under "Demo Project 1\Release", for example:

```
Demo Project 1
    |
    |____Release
            |
            |____ Demo Project 1 v1.0
            |
            |____ Demo Project 1 v2.0
```

and so on...

So how to initialize all this using git Extensions? I do not want to use git shell.

Once this structure has been initialized in my google drive I want to start working by mapping some projects to my local drive in my pc like TFS for visual studio does.

For example, from git extensions i want to connect to my google drive to see the entire directory structure to decide which projects I want to map into my local drive (i mean pull them to my desired mapped local drive). Then, once I have pulled the projects in which i want to work with,  I begin to make my changes (implement new features, etc) and finally do commits that take effect in my local mapped drive and also in the google drive.

How to do all this? I mean prepare this environment in order to work similar to TFS does for visual studio: you map in local the projects in which you want to work with, then you make changes by checking out them, and finally once you have finished your work, you check-in (commit) the changes in order other people in the team to see them.

Comment: That's not how git works.  You should have a single local folder, and use branches for customers and tags for releases.

Comment: Also, use a proper git remote; storing a git repo in a cloud sync service is asking for trouble.

Comment: @SLaks maybe i have not explained well: suppose i have below directory structure. so i put my initial project (first code) in "Customer A\Demo Project 1\Master". Then I create a branch under "Customer A\Demo Project 1\Develop" from  the master and I start making some changes.When I finish to do my changes in develop branch, i create my first release, so i do a branch under release from the develop branch and fix some bugs in it. When all bugs are fixed for the first release, I merge it to master. How is managed this with git?

Comment: You _shouldn't_ have that directory structure.  The whole point of git is to have a single repo in a single directory, and use branches and tags instead of making separate directories.

Answer (score 1):

One more note about using Google Drive with Git. Google Drive can have trouble to sync all Git files in one sync. As result you can mess up the git project files on Google Drive. I use Google Drive only to create a backup of a git repository with the help of [git bundle](http://git-scm.com/blog/2010/03/10/bundles.html)